# Bluetooth/WiFi to USB extension on Mac

Tags: usb, bluetooth

I'm trying a little project out and I wanted to know if it is possible to slave a USB extension to a wireless or Bluetooth network on a Mac?

The setup I have is as follows:

- rechargeable 5v battery
- micro USB in
- USB 2.0 receptacle out
- 7 port USB hub plugged into battery

I want the devices I plug into USB hub to be able to communicate remotely with my MacBook.

I tried what I thought was logical and plugged a Bluetooth module and wireless module into two ports of the USB hub- they power, but I can't find them on my MacBook.

The plan is to make a wireless/Bluetooth flash memory reader by plugging flash USBs into the remaining slots on the extension.

To me, it seems possible, but I now wonder if it isn't. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User Craigbear! I edited your question to tidy up some of the tags and improve the formatting a bit. The 'thanks in advance' is nice but not necessary :) If you feel strongly about thatyou can put it back in by editing your own question. Please have a read of [the tour](/tour) if you haven't already so that you are familiar with how the site works in terms of voting etc. Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

### You cannot plug a bluetooth dongle into a USB hub to make the hub wireless

I can see the logic in what you are trying to do: Mac has bluetooth, so by plugging in a bluetooth dongle into a powered hub, that hub can be accessed by bluetooth. Seems sensible on the face of it.

However, the bluetooth dongle doesn't work that way. It needs something to tell it what to do. An operating system will provide an interface to the dongle so that you can say "I want to pair with *this* device" or "I want to send audio to *that* bluetooth speaker". The USB hub can't tell the bluetooth dongle what to do.

### You *can* buy 'wireless' USB hubs

There are hubs out there which can be set up to act the way you want to. Grabbing [an example product](http://www.icron.com/products/icron-brand/legacy/usb-wi-ranger/) (discontinued):

> The WiRanger® is the world’s first wireless USB 2.0 Hub combining Icron’s patented ExtremeUSB® technology and the industry standard 802.11g radio to deliver **cable-free USB** around the home or office.
>
> The WiRanger wireless USB 2.0 hub is a four-port hub and dongle set that will enable immediate high-speed wireless connectivity with maximum reach extending beyond 30m.

(emphasis mine)

Searching for *wireless USB hub* returns plenty of results, but hardware recommendations are beyond the scope of this site.

#### But consider speed

One last thing is that by going wireless you will almost certainly have a lower throughput than a wired solution. For keyboards and mice this may not be a problem, but since you mentioned a flash reader specifically, I thought I'd give you a heads-up. Reading large amounts of data from a flash card (eg photos) will probably be significantly slower.